# Always on Failback

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover

Does always on supports automatic failback like sql cluster? Since the preferred owners and possible owners are controlled by the AG how can a particular node be set as preferred primary when failback ?

Answer (score 1):

> Does always on supports automatic failback like sql cluster?

Yes, it does. Having said that, it's not something I'd ever set or use with **either** an FCI or AG.

> Since the preferred owners and possible owners are controlled by the AG how can a particular node be set as preferred primary when failback ?

When using SQL Server 2016 and multiple automatic failover targets, you can set the preferred list through powershell or the gui but do not touch anything else such as possible owners.

Again, I would stay clear of autofailback for both FCIs and AGs.

Comment: Yesterday my primary server failed backed to secondary and the back up preference was primary only and hence all the back ups failed on the primary. I will have to implement the ola script for the maintenance since I cannot control the failback

Comment: For a "failback" to occur a cluster event needs to happen, it probably didn't failback it most likely failed over... you have two different things going on here - a question on failback and a failover. @SqlNovice

Comment: Sorry it failed over...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly whether it is supported or not but DEFINITELY not recommended and not possible AFAIK. I can say from experience that this could be counter productive so please avoid this you may get more outage than expected. You can of course fail it back using T-SQL script or powershell, there is no harm in doing so.

Some people try to change preferred owner in WSFC GUI thinking that after failover it may failback because the preferred owner is just the node which they always want to be primary replica, please *avoid* that as well, in most cases after removing owner the AG may not failover on the node which is removed as owner. Basically you should NOT change anything from cluster GUI.

Quoting from [MS BooksOnLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-clustering-and-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server)

> - Do not use the Failover Cluster Manager to manipulate availability    groups, for example: Do not add or remove resources in the clustered
>     service (resource group) for the availability group.
> - Do not change any availability group properties, such as the possible    owners and preferred owners. These properties are set
>     automatically    by the availability group.
> - Do not use the Failover Cluster Manager to move availability groups    to different nodes or to fail over availability groups. The Failover
>     Cluster Manager is not aware of the synchronization status of the
>     availability replicas, and doing so can lead to extended downtime.
>     You must use Transact-SQL or SQL Server Management Studio.